# Embedded-friendly command parser in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, mbed

My use case is generating and parsing AT commands

I'm looking for something similar to Boost.Spirit or https://github.com/ColinH/PEGTL , but friendly to an embedded environment (mbed OS) and doesn't need to be quite as powerful as the aforementioned.  The mbed OS ATParser swings the other way and is a bit too weak/scanf-y for my tastes (no dispresect to the ATParser folks)

Boost.Spirit I can't get to compile under that environment and I am hesitant to try PEGTL for similar reasons in addition to it being a bit complex.

Comment: @sailfish009 lists one possibility.  Any others?

Comment: Another option: https://github.com/Helius/microrl

Answer (score 1):

Not AT-specific, but this looks promising: [embedded-commandline](https://github.com/martinhansdk/embedded-commandline).

To use it, looks like you:

- Create a class that inherits from `Outputter`, which implements the `putchar()` and `puts()` member functions for your platform. (You'll pass a reference to an instance of the class to the `DumbLineEditor` and `CommandManager` constructors.)
- Create classes that derive from `Command`, and implement the `execute()` member function for each of your commands.
- Instantiate a `CommandManager`. Call `CommandManager::addCommand()` with an instance of each of your derived `Command`s.
- Instantiate `DumbLineEditor`, passing references to your `CommandManager` and derived `Outputter` to its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

below project maybe what you looking for:

CMDB: A Command Interpreter with support for used defined commands, subsystems, macros, help and parameter parsing.

https://developer.mbed.org/users/wvd_vegt/code/CMDB/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I'm rolling my own.  If it's not against stackoverflow rules, I'll post the link here.

Comment: Please share the info. Then you can even accept your own answer if you think it's the best one, and you're satisfied with it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer